# EXCEL VBA Dynamic Sum function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to simplify this code. I have 5 button in my excel file; each button is associated with a single G function and each button erase the selected value in column N from the value in the F column on the same line...

This is the actual VBA code

```
Sub G5ELIMINA()
Range("F5").Value = (Range("F5").Value - Range("N5").Value)
End Sub

Sub G6ELIMINA()
Range("F6").Value = (Range("F6").Value - Range("N6").Value)
End Sub

Sub G7ELIMINA()
Range("F7").Value = (Range("F7").Value - Range("N7").Value)
End Sub

Sub G8ELIMINA()
Range("F8").Value = (Range("F8").Value - Range("N8").Value)
End Sub

Sub G9ELIMINA()
Range("F9").Value = (Range("F9").Value - Range("N9").Value)
End Sub

Sub G10ELIMINA()
Range("F10").Value = (Range("F10").Value - Range("N10").Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? To get one button to do it over the range F5-F10?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Sub G5SERIES()
Range("F5").Value = (Range("F5").Value - Range("N5").Value)
Range("F6").Value = (Range("F6").Value - Range("N6").Value)
Range("F7").Value = (Range("F7").Value - Range("N7").Value)
Range("F8").Value = (Range("F8").Value - Range("N8").Value)
Range("F9").Value = (Range("F9").Value - Range("N9").Value)
Range("F10").Value = (Range("F10").Value - Range("N10").Value)
End Sub
```